# How to get filename from dialog box in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

To save file on local machine I open dialog box using this:

```
<a href="data:application/xml;charset=utf-8,your code here" download="filename.html">Save</a>
```

It opens dialog with two fields: filename and filetype.

User can change filename and press button save. How to detect that filename field was changed and return it to client side?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

The built-in Save As dialog is entirely outside the influence of any code running on the page.

You can't get any information from it, not even if the user decided to save or cancel the download.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content --> 
<div class="modal-content"> 
<span class="close">&times;</span> 
<input type="text" id="name"/> 
</div> 
</div> 
<button type="button" onClick="getName()">Save Name</button> 

<script> 
function getName() { 
document.getElementById('name').value; 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Please check this

Comment: That is not the browser's built-in save-as dialog that the question is asking about.